# visible videos only have to play like Facebook on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I found the JavaScript code in net for playing the video when it's visible other videos should pause, but this code when i go to the page all video it's pause but i august the scroll it's playing all videos, i'll submit that code down and i'm fetch the videos from database and through the while loop i'm getting all videos. Anyone help me fix this issues and tell me the better solution for this.

```
<script>
    var videos = document.getElementsByClassName('embed-responsive-item');

            function checkScroll() {

                for(var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {

                    var video = videos[i];
                    //alert(video);
                    var x = video.offsetLeft, y = video.offsetTop, w = video.offsetWidth, h = video.offsetHeight, r = x + w, //right
                        b = y + h, //bottom
                        visibleX, visibleY, visible;

                    visibleX = Math.max(0, Math.min(w, window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth - x, r - window.pageXOffset));
                    visibleY = Math.max(0, Math.min(h, window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - y, b - window.pageYOffset));

                    visible = visibleX * visibleY / (w * h);
                    fraction = 1;
                    //alert(visible);

                    if (visible > fraction) {
                        //alert(visible);
                        video.pause();
                    } else {
                        video.play();
                    }

                }

            }

            window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll, false);
            window.addEventListener('resize', checkScroll, false);
</script>

<?php
while($getSharePer01=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getPostStatus01)){
 extract($getSharePer01);
?>

<video id="sampleMovie" class="embed-responsive-item" height="500" preload controls>
<source src="<?php echo $u_pvid; ?>" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="640" height="360">
<param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":{"url":"HTML5Sample_flv.flv","autoPlay":false,"autoBuffering":true}}' />
</object>
</video>

<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution for this question

```
<script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
             // Get media - with autoplay disabled (audio or video)
             var media = $('video').not("[autoplay='autoplay']");
             var tolerancePixel = 20;

             function checkMedia(){
                 // Get current browser top and bottom
                 var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop() + tolerancePixel;
                 var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - tolerancePixel;

                 media.each(function(index, el) {
                     var yTopMedia = $(this).offset().top;
                     var yBottomMedia = $(this).height() + yTopMedia;

                     if(scrollTop < yBottomMedia && scrollBottom > yTopMedia){ //view explaination in `In brief` section above
                         $(this).get(0).play();
                     } else {
                         $(this).get(0).pause();
                     }
                 });

                 //}
             }
             $(document).on('scroll', checkMedia);
         });
        </script>
```